# Perspective simulation (Z scroll)

Tags: scroll, perspective

I am looking for javascript library that is able to simulate perspective Z scroll.
I would like to create web that should be scrolled like walking throught hall.

Does anybody know some library?

Thanks.

Comment: what have you already tried ?

Comment: In code – none. My teory of functionality si to simulate perspective by resizing all elements and hiding them on-by-one that are closest to me.